# Float to Fraction conversion in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, fractions

While doing exercise on the topic of float type to Fraction type conversion in Python 3.52, I found the difference between the two different ways of conversion.

The first method is:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = 1232.23
>>> f = Fraction(*x.as_integer_ratio())
>>> print(f)
2709702426188841/2199023255552      #Answer
```

The second method is:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = 1232.23
>>> f = Fraction(str(x))
>>> print(f)
123223/100                          #Answer
```

I want to know the reason behind these two different answers? Thank you in advance for your time. Any clue will be very considered. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to programming and Python.

Edited: I found a way to convert inaccurate fraction obtained by first method to accurate by `limit_denominator` method:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = 1232.23
>>> f = Fraction(*x.as_integer_ratio())
>>> f = f.limit_denominator(100)     
>>> print(f)
123223/100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet again it's because floating point numbers aren't stored in base-10 (decimal),  but in base-2 (binary).

A number that is finite length in base-10 might be a repeating decimal in base-2. And because floats are a fixed size, that repeating decimal gets truncated, resulting in inaccuracies.

When you use `as_integer_ratio` for a number that's a repeating decimal in base-2, you will get you a somewhat silly fraction as a result of the slight inaccuracies in the base-10 to base-2 conversion. If you divide those two numbers, the value will be very close to to your original number.

For instance, while 1/10 = 0.1 in base-10 and is not a repeating decimal, it is in fact a repeating decimal in base-2. Just like 1/3 = 0.333... in base-10.

```
>>> (0.1).as_integer_ratio()
(3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)
```

If Python's output was exact, you would see this even when you enter just `0.1` in the prompt, by getting something like 1.00000...01 as the output. But Python *hides* this inaccuracy from you in the general case, leading to confusion.

Comment: Seems like a more accurate answer. Could this be the reason for this anamoly?

 `>>> 0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3 `
 `5.551115123125783e-17`

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb: That's not really the reason, the reason is as I explained, the numbers that can be represented without repeating decimals in base-10 are different than the ones that can be in base-2.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty good question. The reason behind the different results is that `x` is not truly `1232.23` because there is no exact float representation for `1232.23`, so the fractional representation of the nearest float representation of `1232.23` is `2709702426188841/2199023255552`, but when you use `str(1232.23)` it treats it as the exact value `1232.23` and returns the true best fractional representation of the number.