# Unexpected result for fraction

Tags: python

```
>>> From fractions import Fraction

>>> f=Fraction(2/6)
>>> f
Fraction(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)
```

it gives some unexpected result ? why

Comment: What did you expected it to give?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fractions in Python for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893643/fractions-in-python-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Also: [Float to Fraction conversion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172252/float-to-fraction-conversion-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the result of that fraction, use:
`f.__float__()`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `,` instead `/` for fraction

```
from fractions import Fraction

f=Fraction(2,6)
print(f)
```

Comment: Please accept it so that it could be helpful for others that would have the same problem